# Randomly separate space into sections

Tags: javascript, p5.js

this seems like it should be simple, but it's not working out for me at the moment.

I'm trying to create horizontal sections, each of which would then be filled in with textured strokes of a certain (or random) color between that particular section's beginning and end, with the next section beginning immediately at the previous section's end. Here's what I have in code:

note that the w(val) is just percentage of width

```
function vertBG() {
  let sectionsWidths = [0]
  for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    let sectionWidth = random(w(.13),w(.3))
    sectionsWidths.push(sectionWidth)
  }
  let sections = []
  for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    let begin = sectionsWidths[i];
    let end = sectionsWidths[i] + sectionsWidths[i+1]
    sections.push([begin,end])
  }
  console.log(sectionsWidths)
  console.log(sections)
  for (let i = 0; i < sections.length; i++) {
    for (let x = sections[i][0]; x < sections[i][1]; x += w(.01)) {
      let r = random(155,255)
      let g = random(155,255)
      let b = random(155,255)
      texStr(x, 0, x, height, w(.2), r, g, b, 50)
    }
  }
}
```

EDIT adding p5 editor link here https://editor.p5js.org/anton.ermkv/sketches/Dk0sHI771

It works for the first two sections, but not past that as I get the following from logging the sections array:

```
0: (2) [0, 187.61733953724615]
1: (2) [187.61733953724615, 325.3773163144011]
2: (2) [137.75997677715495, 286.15264510712586]
3: (2) [148.39266832997092, 297.9690613041166]
4: (2) [149.5763929741457, 302.7814557082951]
5: (2) [153.2050627341494, 346.3200062647462]
```

On line 2, instead of getting the sum of 187... and 137... I just have 137... again and so on down line.

Expected output is to have vertical stripes of varying width going across the canvas. So the array should look something like:

```
0: (2) [0, 130]
1: (2) [130, 290]
2: (2) [290, 445]
3: (2) [445, 600]
```

Thanks to anyone having a look at this!

Comment: What's the expected output exactly?

Comment: Can you paste an example of the correct output? Or at least, how you expect it to look like?

Answer (score 1):

Replace this line:

```js
let end = sectionsWidths[i] + sectionsWidths[i+1]
```

With this one:

```js
let end = sectionsWidths[i+1]
```

Basically, you just need to jump to the next index via `i+1` and get the value, instead of adding the previous and the next value.

That is, if I correctly understand the expected outcome which is not included in the answer.

---

**Update:** after your clarification, I think this code is what you're looking for:

```js
  for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    const begin = sections[i-1] ? sections[i-1][1] : sectionsWidths[i];
    const end = begin + sectionsWidths[i+1]; // Or sectionsWidths[i]?
    sections.push([begin,end])
  }
```

Comment: That's something that I tried, but then the sections array ends up looking something like this: `0: (2) [0, 142.79808255149982]
1: (2) [142.79808255149982, 125.60748815280385]
2: (2) [125.60748815280385, 174.32071663881652]
3: (2) [174.32071663881652, 172.77376112071798]
4: (2) [172.77376112071798, 185.3945339309983]
5: (2) [185.3945339309983, 158.63024690989405]`

Comment: Can you paste the expected outcome in your answer above?

Comment: That seems to be the correct output, if I compare it with the outcome you've pasted above.

Comment: The start and end numbers in the arrays you've just pasted exactly correspond to the expected output in your answer.

Comment: It's correct for the first section that spans 0-142, and it's correct in beginning the second section at 142, but it doesn't continue to add (or move across the canvas horizontally) after that. Which is the same result as I was getting before. Each start should match the previous section's end and add the sectionWidth value to it, so it should always increase.

Comment: 1st pair [0, 142], 2nd [142, 125], 3rd, [125, 174] and so on.

Comment: It's unclear, to be honest, by what you mean "doesn't continue to add" or "move across the canvas horizontally". The array values are placed in the way you've described in the expected outcome above. [ 0, 1 ], [1 ,2 ], [2,3]. Maybe you need to share a working snippet so that we can check the full code. Without the rnd(), w() and other methods it's almost impossible to dig deeper.

Comment: Sorry, I'll try to clarify: by moving across horizontally, I mean that if the first stripe spans 0-142, then the second should begin at 142 and end at x > 142. I want to do this by adding the next value from the sectionWidth array to that section's start point (in this case 142).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247716/discussion-between-kostas-minaidis-and-anton-e).

Comment: Answer updated. Please check. @AntonE